# Ubuntu 17.04 eats RAM after suspend

Tags: suspend, ram, swap

I have a slow laptop, namely acer E5-411-c79a. My main concern is that after a while ubuntu eats all the ram and swap area/file. Yes, I read that, it uses for caching purposes and having memory at 90% is great. I'm fine with that. I never really shut it down, just suspend it. And after 4-5 days, it just stops working,meaning even the cursor isn't able to move only after 7-8 seconds. I opened the gnome-system-monitor and saw that ram and swap are 100%. If anybody experienced same behavior, please let me know. I'm running ubuntu-budgie 17.04. 4GB RAM and 2 GB swap (the installer made it that size).

Comment: and there were no processes, that would take up that much ram space

Comment: Caching doesn't use swap. You need to click on the hamburger menu (`☰`) of the System Monitor application and select `All Processes` to see if there are actually no processes using enough memory.

Comment: I will try that, I just need to wait 4-5 days :) . Thank you.